# How to draw labels to the graph with passes?

Tags: python, plot, graph, seaborn, axis-labels

I've built a graph, but there're a lot of labels on the x axis, as a result, the graph is poorly readable. How to make so that labels are drawn with passes, for example, through two?

My code:

```
i = 0

for d in data['pickup_datetime']:
    i+=1
    print(d, type(d), sep='    ')
    if (i == 5):
        break
```

```
2016-03-14 17:24:55    <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
2016-06-12 00:43:35    <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
2016-01-19 11:35:24    <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
2016-04-06 19:32:31    <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
2016-03-26 13:30:55    <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
```

```
d = data['pickup_datetime']
df3 = pd.DataFrame(d)
df3['dayofyear'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df3['pickup_datetime']).dayofyear

plot = sns.countplot(x='dayofyear', data=df3, color='LightGreen')
plot.figure.set_size_inches(16, 10)
for item in plot.get_xticklabels():
    item.set_rotation(90)
```

[image: down_graph]

Comment: I would do `plt.figure(figsize=(10, 20))` and `sns.countplot(y=df.DateTime.dt.dayofyear, data=df, orient='h')`. Because what you want is difficult if not impossible, because of the way ticks work. The axis is discrete, so each bar has its own tick location.

Comment: Put `ticks, labels = plt.xticks()` & `labels = list(labels)` in order after calling `sns.countplot` then print ticks and labels.

Comment: Just use `plt.xticks(rotation=90)` to rotate the xticks. The for-loop isn't necessary.

Comment: It all doesn't work, cause I haven't got plt, i don't use matplotlib

Comment: `matplotlib` is a dependency for seaborn, so there's not really a good reason not to import it. _Seaborn is a Python data visualization library based on matplotlib. It provides a high-level interface for drawing attractive and informative statistical graphics._ You really are using matplotlib. [seaborn: statistical data visualization](https://seaborn.pydata.org/)

Comment: Yeah, I know, but there's no plt in seaborn.countplot, I can't use it, so I've created the new variable "plot", but I can't make labels with it, it's true

Comment: Many of the plt methods work for formatting seaborn plots and plt method can be used to annotate seaborn plots.